# is it a mongoose documentation population typos?

Tags: mongoose

I'm reading about mongoose population [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), and I'm not sure if I properly understand this line:

```
console.log('The author is %s', story.creator.name);
```

because I can not find any 'creator' field for story schema, but what I see is that its fields are 'author, title, fans'. To me, that line must be like:

```
console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
```

Am I missing something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. You are right, it should be

> console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);